# iOS 9.1 still has this serious bug with local notifications?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I dont know if i am missing something very big here, or that Apple does.
Its a month we are dealing with this bug of notifications that fire with no reason. (Xcode 7.1 , iOS9.1)

1.Even when i delete an app from my iPhone, all its `UILocalNotifications`, continue to fire for days later, even when the app is not on the device (!)
How can i be sure it will not happen to our users ?? is it only a development bug?

2.When i have an app on the device, and i print all the notifications with :

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSArray *eventArray = [app scheduledLocalNotifications];
for (int i=0; i<[eventArray count]; i++)
{
    UILocalNotification* oneEvent = [eventArray objectAtIndex:i];
     NSLog(@"%@",oneEvent.fireDate);
}
```

I can see all the days and hours of my notifications , and i can see there is no notification for a specific day and time , but the system ***DOES KEEP FIRE A NOTIFICATION THAT IS NOT EVEN IN THE LIST !*** , and this is something not happens once, but over a full month since iOS9 .

3. We where thinking that the problem is with :

> [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

but even when we cancel each one of them(loop) they fires, and we found out that this line DOES remove the notification from the list (that same list i get with the code above ) ***but in practice it continue to fire !***

Is there an option that this list is not showing me the real system list ?
Or does the system just "Detached" from the list ?

I can show how i am setting a notification but i am sure there is only one way to do that, and that when something is not in the list, it shouldn't being fired .

This is the most annoying bug i have ever had with iOS.

Comment: Never saw a notification firing when the app is not on device. What happens when you tap on the notification? Is some application opened? Most likely you had multiple instances of the app installed and one of them is still there on your device.